# Apple Developer Enterprise Program - Change Account Holder

Tags: ios, accounts, administrator, enterprise

I have access to our company Apple Developer Enterprise Program account as *Admin*. The guy with the *Account Holder* role left the company a few weeks ago, but his Apple is still linked to the account as Account Holder.

How do I change my access type from Admin to Account Holder?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you refer to the [linked](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/) support document and clarify the user roles of the people involved?

Comment: Hi @NimeshNeema thanks for your reply! My case refer to Apple Developer Enterprise Program with me as Admin and the person who left the company as Account Holder.

Comment: Most likely, the email address domain used as Apple ID to log in as account holder must be registered/created by your organization. You should be able to get hold of it via IT and re-gain access.

Comment: Thank you, it seems quite clear. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to gain access to the email account used for logging in as Account Holder.

Most likely, the email address domain used as Apple ID to login must be registered/created by your organization. You'll need to follow the proper chain of command internally and gain access to the email account via IT.

Once you have the access, either continue using it or assign the Account Holder role to your Apple ID.

You can refer to the Developer Program roles here:

- [Apple Developer Program Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)

Comment: What if he didn’t use an organization email address and died? I’m serious. I’m in a similar situation, only the guy didn’t die but is acting hostile after leaving the company, and his email is from a private domain.